# Blowfish encryption function(BF_encrypt) in C

Tags: c, encryption, blowfish

I am trying to understand the BlowFish Encryption algorithm. I am having some problems which are described below in full details:

Here are functions:

```
 void BF_encrypt (data, encrypt)
       BF_LONG *data;   //data is array of two members i.e ti[0] and ti[1]  
                       //and BF_LONG is defined as unsigned long in header file
       int encrypt;     //encrypt is defined as 1
  {
    register BF_LONG l, r, *p, *s;  //BF_LONG is defined as unsigned long in header file
    p = key_P;                      //key_P is declared as BF_LONG key_P[16 + 2];
    s = &(key_S[0]);                //key_S is declared as BF_LONG key_S[4 * 256];
    l = data[0];                    //data[0]=ti[0]
    r = data[1];                    //data[1]=ti[1]
    l ^= p[0];                      //Bitwise ex-or of l with p[0];
    BF_ENC (r, l, s, p[1]);
    }
```

And here is BF_ENC function:

```
  #define BF_ENC(LL,R,S,P) \
    LL^=P; \
    LL^=((( S[        (R>>24L)      ] + \
        S[0x0100+((R>>16L)&0xff)])^ \
        S[0x0200+((R>> 8L)&0xff)])+ \
        S[0x0300+((R     )&0xff)])&0xffffffff;
```

Here are my questions:

What does "\" mean in every ending line in BF_ENC?

R>>24L, I can get it that it is shifting to right. L is long here but I am not getting its presence here. What is the effect of L on data?

Last question is that what is BF_ENC function doing over all, just a overview not in depth.

If you need any more information, I am here.
Thanks!

Comment: Beware to use the right terms in cryptography. Blowfish is a *block cipher* rather than an *encryption algorithm*. You can use blowfish within a [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) such as CBC to create an encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BF_ENC` is a C-style macro. Usually those are delimited by the end of line character. The `\` escape character is just there to indicate that the next line should be considered part of this line. So everything up to `0xffffffff;` is part of the macro.

---

The effect of `L` is that on many languages the primitive type of the output may depend on both operands. The `L` makes 24 (and 16 and 8) *literals* of the type `long`. This will make sure that the output is of the correct primitive type (of at least 32 bit). In particular it makes sure that the output is large enough to store the 32 bit information.

For shifts this doesn't make much sense (you wouldn't expect a shift of more than 64 bits, so the output could be just the primitive type put in the left operand) but language designers like symmetry - with operators such as `+` and `*` - and dislike special cases.

Looking at a previous question I found:

> yes, this was my thought as well. Afair, this really worked in K&R (`1 << 1L` was of type `long` like `1 + 1L` is in ISO C), which is why I asked where the code is from...

so make sure you verify that this macro is working correctly in your environment. To understand blowfish you may be better off looking at more modern code that doesn't contain macro's at all.

---

`BF_ENC` shows Blowfishes F function which is the round function (Feistel function) of Blowfish.

It's on the upper right [of the Wikipedia page about Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29) and is described as:

> The diagram to the upper right shows Blowfish's F-function. The function splits the 32-bit input into four eight-bit quarters, and uses the quarters as input to the S-boxes. The outputs are added modulo 2^32 and XORed to produce the final 32-bit output.

Comment: Thanks! I have got everything you told.
Now, I need only one more clarification that what does this mean?
S[(R>>24L)]
I don't know how long it is making shift? For example if I have r=20 then how much it will be shifted. 
P.S: I am new to this thing so guide me little. Thanks!

Comment: The idea is that the R value is 32 bits and then shifted right 24 bits, meaning that you are left with the first (leftmost) 8 bits. If R is 20 then it will evaluate to zero of course.